# RESTFul Service - PUT Call failing with http 411 error

Tags: java, rest, put

I am trying to invoke a Rest service with input method as "PUT". When I execute the service, I am getting a HTTP 411 error. HTTP 411 relates to Content Length, I even tried setting the content length to 0, but it is still failing. Please find the code snippet for the same below, can you please help me in fixing this issue?

```
        URL url = new URL(
                "https://xxx/api/1.0/empPortalAcknowledgeAndUnassigned/updateCheckInStatus"
                        + inputParm);
        HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
        conn.setRequestMethod("PUT");
        conn.setRequestProperty("Authorization", access_token);
        // conn.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/json");
        conn.setRequestProperty("Accept", "application/json");
        conn.setConnectTimeout(1000);
        conn.setReadTimeout(1000);
        conn.setRequestProperty("Content-Length", "0");
        conn.addRequestProperty("Content-Length", "0");
        if (conn.getResponseCode() != HttpURLConnection.HTTP_OK) {
            throw new RuntimeException("Failed : HTTP error code : " + conn.getResponseCode());
        }
        System.out.println("Output from Server ...." + "Response Code::" + conn.getResponseCode() + "\n");
        conn.disconnect();
```

Comment: when you are not sending any data at all in `PUT` method, why are you using `PUT` in the first place? If you have an option you should change the method to `GET` and remove the lines where you are adding / setting content-length. That should work.

Answer (score 0):

You try to create a https connection via a `HttpURLConnection`. Use `HttpsURLConnection` instead. (Http**s**UrlConnection)

Comment: Tried changing it to HttpsUrlConnection but it did not work. Still same error is thrown.